# How to define event listener in the service?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

In Drupal 8 is possible to use event subscriber that is the separate class that defines the callback that should be called on the defined event. See  [Event Systems Overview & How To Subscribe To and Dispatch Events](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/event-systems-overview-how-to-subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events)

But I'm wondering how to define event listener that will trigger the method of the service on the desired event?

here Symfony references:

[Events and Event Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/event_dispatcher.html)

[Built-in Symfony Events](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/events.html)

Comment: You can't define an event listener in a service (that wouldn't make sense, what's guaranteeing that the service has even been instantiated when the event is raised?). But you can inject a service into the event listener, and call a method on it that way, which achieves the same thing

Comment: You could point an event listener to any php callable, but Drupal doesn't use event listeners, only subscribers. An event subscriber class is always a service, implementing getSubscribedEvents() to define which class method to trigger on the desired event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I think you are asking about implementing minimalistic single responsibility event listeners declared in the YML config file, like in this Java example:

```
class MyListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    myTextArea.append('Hello from MyListener');
  }
}
```

That is not possible since this is this what the `EventDispatcher` actually does:

```
    public function addSubscriber(EventSubscriberInterface $subscriber)
    {
        foreach ($subscriber->getSubscribedEvents() as $eventName => $params) {
            if (is_string($params)) {
                $this->addListener($eventName, array($subscriber, $params));
            } elseif (is_string($params[0])) {
                $this->addListener($eventName, array($subscriber, $params[0]), isset($params[1]) ? $params[1] : 0);
            } else {
                foreach ($params as $listener) {
                    $this->addListener($eventName, array($subscriber, $listener[0]), isset($listener[1]) ? $listener[1] : 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can still have your separate `ActionListener`'s, but you would have to write some code to call them from your implementation of `EventSubscriberInterface`.

Comment: I guess it is the correct answer. But also, it worth to mention that better implement EventSubscriberInterface in the service where the event callback will be placed and add the tag - { name: event_subscriber } in *.services.yml file. In the result we have a service and the event callback in the same place.

Comment: @voleger, since this is the correct answer, would you please mark it as the answer. Thank you!